# NoReverseMatch at /polls/upload/ Reverse for 'imageupload' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: python, django

I am tried to upload image. Upto select photo it worked fine but when I clicked upload it gave following errors:

```
Django Version: 1.10
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['polls.apps.PollsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\virtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\virtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\virtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\virtualEnv\mysite\polls\views.py" in home
  103.             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))

File "D:\virtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "D:\virtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  389.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /polls/upload/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'imageupload' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I tried following model:

```
class Upload(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to="images/")    
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from uploader.models import UploadForm,Upload
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)       
        if img.is_valid():
            img.save()  
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

Template:

```
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <h1>picture</h1>
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}} 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    {% for img in images %}
        {{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ img.pic.url }}">{{ img.pic.name }}</a>
        ({{img.upload_date}})<hr />
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and ModelForm:

```
class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
```

polls urls:

```
url(r'^upload/$', views.home, name='imageupload'),
```

mysite urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Could anyone suggest the ways to fix it.

Comment: Show your urls.py file

Comment: please share your urls.py

Comment: This is my url: url(r'^upload/$', views.home, name='imageupload'),

Comment: Are you using include with namespace to include this urls.py file?

Comment: In polls urls, I used: app_name = 'polls' and also use include in mysite urls to include polls_urls. I already posted my both urls in the question.

Comment: try to change `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls'))` to `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls'))` and then use `polls:imageupload` in reverse

Comment: @Morishiri If you set an `app_name` like that, the namespace will default to the value of `app_name`. So in this case, you only need to change it to `polls:imageupload`, you don't need to pass `namespace='polls'`.

Comment: Thats right @knbk, I only need to add polls: before imageupload in the reverse. Though both way it gives same result. Thanks both of you.